# $\ X \sim U(0,1) $ find pdf of $\ Y= e^X $

Tags: probability, probability-theory

$ X \sim Uni(0,1) $ and $\ Y = e^X $

Find $\ Y $ pdf

So if $\ X $ is uniform then $\ f_x(x) = 1 $ for every $\ 0 \le x \le 1 $

$$\ P\{Y \le y\} = P\{e^X \le y\} = P\{x \le \ln y \} = \ln y $$

What I don't understand is the last part of the equation, could someone explain to me why $\ P\{x \le ln y\} = \ln y $ ?

Comment: You are looking for the PDF right? In your last step if you wanted the CDF you would integrate under ln(y), but PDF, take the derivative, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $X$ is uniform, so $P(X<a)=a$ for any $a \in [0,1]$. Substitute $a=\ln(y)$.

To see why, the CDF of the uniform distribution will be:

$P(X<a) = \int\limits_0^a f_X(x)dx = \int\limits_0^a dx = (a-0)=a$

Comment: Thank you! Understood now.

Comment: You're welcome. You can mark this as the accepted answer by ticking the checkmark below the voting button if it solved your problem.